# Nilpotent/ Quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, nilpotence

I am little fuzzy on how can we conclude that if $L$ is a Lie algebra, and if $L/Z(L)$ is nilpotent, then so is L. Where $Z(L)$ is the center of $L$, namely $Z(L) = \{z \in L \vert [xz] = 0 \ for \ all \ x \in L\}$.

The argument I saw was $L^n \subset Z(L)$, why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $L$ to be nilpotent, $L^n=0$ for some $n$. But we are given $L/Z$
is nilpotent, where $Z=Z(L)$ is the centre of $L$. Thus $(L/Z)^n=0$.
What does this mean for $L^n$? In the natural projection map $\pi:L\to L/Z$
then $(L/Z)^n$ is the image of $L^n$, i.e., $\pi(L^n)=(L/Z)^n=0$.
This means that $L^n$ is contained in the kernel of $\pi$, that is
$L^n\subseteq Z$.

That implies $L^{n+1}=[L^n,L]\subseteq[Z,L]=0$ as $Z$ is the centre of $L$,
so $L$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you for the help that was very clear. Sorry for the bothering.

Comment: If we have not $Z(L)$ but a nilpotent ideal $K$ of $L$ and that $L/K$ nilpotent, can we conclude that $L$ is nilpotent? @Angina Seng

Comment: @Lam18373 no you cannot conclude this. This argument works for nilpotent replaced by solvable though. The reason you cannot is because if $L^n\subset K$, we can just say that $L^{n+1}=[L^n,L]\subset[K,L]$ but this is not necessarily a subset of $K^2L=[K,K]$

Answer (score 1):

Because, since $L/Z(L)$ is nilpotent, $\bigl(L/Z(L)\bigr)^n=\{0\}$ for some $n$, and this is the same thing as asserting that $L^n\subset Z(L)$. So, $L^{n+1}=\{0\}$.